# Finding the Redis config file in macOS

Tags: macos, redis, config, file-location

I have installed Redis on my Mac and now I am trying to access Redis config file `redis.conf`. Where is it located in macOS?

I have tried looking at various resources, but could not find any helpful information.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 6):

If Redis is running and you can access it with `redis-cli` - try `INFO` command. It would expose the location of the config file as the `config_file:` field.

Example:

```console
$ redis-cli INFO | grep config_file
```

---

There is a chance, however, that the Redis was launched without any config file. Then the `config_file:` would be empty.

You can also start Redis with the specific config file like:

```console
$ </path/to/>redis-server  </path/to/>redis.conf
```

To find the location of `redis-server` *executable*, you can once again use the `INFO` command:

```console
$ redis-cli INFO | grep executable
```

---

For more information refer to the [Redis documentation](https://redis.io/docs/management/config/).

Answer (score 0):

I was confused with the redis having redis.conf file, tried a lot of methods to find it but was unable to find it out.
here is where I found out in my machine (Mac OS).

1. ls **/opt/homebrew/etc/redis.conf**
2. ls **/opt/homebrew/bin/redis.conf**
3. ls **/etc/redis/redis.conf**
4. ls **/etc/redis.conf**
5. ls **/var/lib/redis/redis.conf**

For me it was inside /opt/homebrew/etc

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For those who installed `redis-stack-server` with *Homebrew*: I found the config file at `/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/redis-stack-server/<<VERSION>>/etc/redis-stack.conf`.